# Behaviour of recvmsg() for udp

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, recv

I am sending n multiple udp packets in single message header using `sendmsg()` in my Cpp application. Also I am receiving messages using `recvmsg()` from the other end. The problem is on receiving side. I am not able to get messages in different `msghdr.msg_iov` entries(just the way I send), Instead I am getting the whole content of all the n messages in the first `struct iovec` of `msghdr.msg_iov` of itself?

Is there any method to keep my messages in sperate `struct iovec` of `msghdr.msg_iov` on the receiving side? Or do I have to some use custom twaek to separate the messages(like sending `sizeof(message)+message` instead of just `message`)